# Converting to passive voice

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

I use a lot of first person and second person when writing, like *you, we, our,* etc. However, I want to write strictly using passive voice. I noticed that I use the phrase, *"we can", "we have"* and *"now we have"* a lot. What are substitutes I can use to replace those phrases to passive voice?

---

Here are some examples of my writing that I am having difficult converting to passive voice:

*"We can apply this technique by introducing a polarization filter which restricts light into a single plane."*

*"Now that we have a basic understanding of unpolarized light, we can now take a dive into polarized light."*

Comment: "This technique can be applied by ..."  The second one is a little more complicated.

Comment: No sense can have been made by the thing that seems to be being asked for by you can be plainly seen by anyone. *“Now that a basic understand of unpolarized has been had by us, a dive into polarized light can now be taken by us.”* *“This technique can be applied by us with a polarization filter having been introduced by us whose light has been restricted into a single plane by the filter.”*

Comment: If you think this something that  ̶p̶e̶o̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶ will be wanted to be read by people throughout, then you may have another think coming. :) Since you cannot honestly be asking for this, what you are asking for is unclear. Please edit your post for what you actually want. Passivization means inverting subject and object in transitive clauses with of the form “NP1 VERB NP2” to create the correspondingly inflected version of “NP2 **BE** VERBed ***BY*** NP1” as demonstrated by *The dog bit the man > The man **was** bitten **by** the dog*; see also [writing.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"We can apply this technique -> This technique can be applied

which restricts light ->by which light is restricted

"Now that we have a basic understanding of unpolarized light, -> Now that a basic  understanding of unpolarized light has been attained/achieved

we can now take a dive ." -> a dive can be taken